# Hugo Error - Current theme does not support current version

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-s3, hugo

I'm attempting to build my hugo site but when I run `hugo check` I see the following error log:

```
ERROR: 2017/09/10 Current theme does not support Hugo version 0.14. Minimum version required is 0.18
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/_default/baseof.html:2: function "default" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: redefinition of template "main"
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/_default/single.html:7: function "humanize" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: redefinition of template "main"
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/_default/terms.html:12: function "relLangURL" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/index.html:6: function "default" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/menu-contextual.html:12: function "humanize" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/page-header.html:9: function "default" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/site-footer.html:4: function "now" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/site-header.html:1: function "default" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/social-follow.html:5: function "dict" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/partials/summary.html:3: function "humanize" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: theme/post/single.html:11: function "humanize" not defined
ERROR: 2017/09/10 template: redefinition of template "main"
```

It says that I need Hugo version 0.18 but when I run `sudo apt-get install hugo` it tells me:

```
hugo is already the newest version
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
```

So I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error. Has anyone run into this error? Know how I can fix it?

Comment: Please include the output from running `hugo env` in your question. Also, this doesn't really seem to be related to any of the tags you've added to your question except `hugo`. Certainly not the AWS or S3 tags.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running this on an EC2 instance and deploying the website on S3. That's why those tags are there. Also it doesn't seem like `hugo env` is a support command.

Comment: That still doesn't seem relevant to the actual problem you are having. You appear to be running Hugo 0.14, which is an old version, and the `upgrade` command doesn't seem to work. I suggest going here to download the latest version and install it manually https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases

Comment: Is the `upgrade` command just `sudo apt-get upgrade hugo`? Also are you just saying that I should go to the repository and clone it? How would I use it to upgrade the version of Hugo I have installed?

Comment: The link I provided is to the releases page, which has binaries you can download. Although you could try `sudo apt-get upgrade hugo` first to see if that works, which would be the better option. How did you install Hugo originally? If you used `apt` then use that to upgrade.

Comment: Yes, I installed it with `apt` and I tried `upgrade` but it didn't work. Also I downloaded the tar file and extracted it but I don't know how to install the new version of hugo. There is a file in there called `hugo` but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Just run it. The Hugo application is a single file.

Comment: I did not know that, but how do I get it to replace the hugo version currently on my system? Like when I run `hugo version` it still says that I have hugo 0.14. Do I need to put the file somewhere?

Comment: Change your `PATH` to point to the new version. Or run `which hugo` to find out where the current version is and overwrite that maybe, but that's not very clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not getting the latest version of Hugo using `apt` then you should attempt to download it directly from the [Github repository](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases). Click on the latest release (or whichever version you need). Once you're on the release page, scroll down to the Downloads section and then download the file by clicking on it or by using `wget` download the compressed file. Then extract the file and run `./hugo version` to confirm the version.

Answer (score 11):

Ubuntu's main download repos are maintained by Canonical, and they are outdated for GoHugo latest releases. Hence, `sudo apt upgrade hugo` will not be much of help. Even now, hugo latest release is 0.48 dated August but the apt gives me only upto 0.40 outdated as of April.

> Always try to use `sudo snap install hugo` in Ubuntu for up-to-date experience with Go Hugo. Snaps are maintained and updated very well. So even if you miss manually to update your packages, it seamlessly updates in background within 12 hours of releases after arriving at Snap Stores.
>
> Uninstall all the instances of Hugo and try fresh installation with snaps if possible because new versions always tend to leave support for some old configs. You can try verifying your needed hugo version using `sudo snap search hugo` which gives details of which latest version is available in snap store currently.
>
> Or manually you could download the latest release [link](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/releases) and update your version and finally check with `sudo hugo version`. You can also confirm its primary location in system by `whereis hugo` and replacing it with newer versions.